# Spring, cannot change values of a @RequestScope service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying create a log service to store two variables, that i will be using during the life of the http request. The problem is that i cannot change the fields. i tried setters, init methods and I can see in the debugger the change in the values but after getting out of the method the fields are null

the only reason is that i not modifying the same object but i have the `RequestScope`....

```
@Service
@RequestScope
public class LogService {

    private String id;
    private String type;

    public void init(String id, String type) {
       this.id = id;
       this.type = type;
    }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Controller {

    private OtherService otherService;
    private LogService logService;

    @PostMapping(value = "create", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody BodyObject body) {

       /* in the debugger i can see that the values are set in the object but after getting out of the logService.init the object the variables are null */
        logService.init("service", body.getId());

         /* here both fields are null and also inside other services using the  logService */
         otherService.execute(body);
        .....
    }
```

Comment: *"after getting out of the method the fields are null"* Out of what method? --- The `Controller.create()` method? When that method returns, that's the end of the request, so why would you expect the values to be retained?

Comment: sorry I meant that after getting out of the logService.init method, and calling for other services the values are null

Comment: How is `Controller.logService` assigned?

Comment: Lombok: @AllArgsConstructor is creating the constructor for the injection. i think there is a problem with how i run the project. i'm using docker and adding to the java opt
`"$JAVA_OPTS_APPEND -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8797"`

to allow me to connect the ide debugger. but i tested without the debugger and is working as expected.

Comment: The debugger is not running in the context of a request, so why would you expect it to see the request-scoped values?

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce. Here is full [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```java
@Service
@RequestScope
public class LogService {

    private String id;
    private String type;

    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    public void init(String id, String type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LogService[id=" + this.id + ", type=" + this.type + "]";
    }

}
```

```java
@Service
public class ScopeService {

    @Autowired
    private LogService logService;

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("ScopeService: " + this.logService);
        System.out.println("  id=" + this.logService.getId() + ", type=" + this.logService.getType());
    }

}
```

```java
@RestController
public class ScopeController {

    @Autowired
    private ScopeService scopeService;
    @Autowired
    private LogService logService;

    @GetMapping("/dmz/scope")
    public String create(@RequestParam String id, @RequestParam String type) throws InterruptedException {
        this.logService.init(id, type);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        this.scopeService.test();
        return this.logService.toString();
    }

}
```

The `Thread.sleep()` is to test parallel web request processing, to make sure the `LogService` truly is request-scoped.

So I use the following 2 URLs, submitted within 10 seconds of each other:
`http://localhost:8080/dmz/scope?id=1&type=TEST1`
`http://localhost:8080/dmz/scope?id=2&type=TEST2`

They return pages showing: `LogService[id=1, type=TEST1]`
and: `LogService[id=2, type=TEST2]`

My log shows:

```
2020-05-01 13:10:29.117 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter      : Before request [GET /dmz/scope?id=1&type=TEST1]
2020-05-01 13:10:30.312 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter      : Before request [GET /dmz/scope?id=2&type=TEST2]
ScopeService: LogService[id=1, type=TEST1]
  id=1, type=TEST1
2020-05-01 13:10:39.162  INFO 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] shared.EventLogger                       : EVENT: ServletRequestHandledEvent
2020-05-01 13:10:39.162 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter      : REQUEST DATA : GET /dmz/scope?id=1&type=TEST1]
ScopeService: LogService[id=2, type=TEST2]
  id=2, type=TEST2
2020-05-01 13:10:40.319  INFO 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] shared.EventLogger                       : EVENT: ServletRequestHandledEvent
2020-05-01 13:10:40.320 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter      : REQUEST DATA : GET /dmz/scope?id=2&type=TEST2]
```